# Vertical spacing in tabular environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Text_wrapping_in_tables

In the link above, they give a description of a tabular environment and I need to have something similar. However, I would like the first and second column to be vertically centered. I've tried the `array` package and using `m{...}` but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

For example, this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | m{2cm} | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result, is almost the same as the image on wikibooks, there is no vertical centering whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Would you mind showing us what you've tried?

Comment: You should always/where possible include a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) in your questions, which begins at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}`, displaying what you've got so far and the issues you face, it should include all necessary `\usepackage`s which are required to get to that point, but none more.

Comment: Why only the first and second column? What about the third column: Should the cells in that column by centered vertically as well?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the third as well!

Comment: please provide minimal work example (mwe) and with it show what you try so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried the array package and using `m{...}` but this doesn't seem to work.

Changing `p{5cm}` to `m{5cm}`, i.e., changing

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | m{5cm} |}
```

should achieve what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array} % for 'm' column type
\begin{document}
With width specified:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | m{5cm} |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: omg, I feel stupid now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `booktabs` to improve the look of the table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{m{1.8cm}*2{S[table-format=2.0]}m{5cm}}
            \toprule
            Day & {\makecell[c]{Min Temp\\(\textdegree C)}} & {\makecell[c]{Max Temp\\(\textdegree C)}} & Summary \\ 
            \midrule
            Monday & 11 & 22 & A clear day with lots of sunshine.\newline  
            However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \midrule
            Tuesday & 9 & 19 & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions.\newline Clear spells 
            across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
            but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ 
            \midrule
            Wednesday & 10 & 21 & Rain will still linger for the morning.\newline 
            Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
            throughout the evening. \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]